# Filter data using LINQ from two table

Tags: linq

I have two table :

**Table 1 : Items**

```
ItemsId  Name_En   
  1      Cream
  2      Oil
  3      Detergent
  4      Soap
```

**Table 2 : ItemsCommon**

```
 ItemsCommonId  ItemsId    Name_En         CategoryId
   1                1        Face Cream          3
   2                2        Head Oil            3
   3                1        Foot Cream          4
   4                2        Body Oil            4
```

Now what I want if user search items by categoryid = 3 then it will show result like :

```
ItemsId   Name_En   
 1      Face Cream
 2      Head Oil
 3      Detergent
 4      Soap
```

or search items by categoryid = 4 then result will be :

```
ItemsId   Name_En
  1      Foot Cream
  2      Body Oil
  3      Detergent
  4      Soap
```

but if user search by other categoryid except 3, 4 then result will be same as Items table :

```
ItemsId  Name_En   
 1      Cream
 2      Oil
 3      Detergent
 4      Soap
```

I try this method..

```
public List<Items> SearchItemsByCategory(int categoryid )
    {
        var items= (from i in db.Items
                    join ic in db.ItemsCommon on i.ItemsId equals ic.ItemsCommonId 
                    into tempJoin
                    from t2 in tempJoin.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    select new { t2.Id,t2.Name,t2.ItemsId,t2.CategoryId }).ToList();
        return items;

       // var result = casePartyRoles.Where(c=>c.)
    }
```

Any suggestion really appreaciated !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
public List<Items> SearchItemsByCategory(int categoryid )
    {
        var items= (from i in db.Items
                    join ic in db.ItemsCommon.Where(x=>x.CategoryId == categoryid )
                     on i.ItemsId equals ic.ItemsId 
                    into tempJoin
                    from t2 in tempJoin.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    select new { i.ItemsId,Name_En  = t2==null?i.Name_En: t2.Name_En }).ToList();
        return items;

       // var result = casePartyRoles.Where(c=>c.)
    }
```